# jquery ajax returned data printing outside div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Sorry but i really didn't know how to frame my question in one line.

The scenario is that i have a index file (all files i'll be talking about are php unless exclusively defined) which includes other files such as header.php, footer.php, sidebar.php and about.php (this is the landing page). Now i've written a jquery script (included in footer.php) which loads other pages through AJAX into the "changing_div". The loading of other pages happened without any issues till they were html files, but as soon as i changed them over to php files (because i needed to add more functionality), the website started to break.

What i mean by break is that, say i have 5 pages out of which 2 are without sidebars, so when i go from the landing page (which has the sidebar) to another page which doesn't have sidebar, the content of the this new page without the sidebar are supposed to (and they do) take the full 12 columns (i'm using bootstrap 3), but if i then go to back to the page with a sidebar, the sidebar isn't there, instead the "#page-content" div (of originally 8 columns) takes up full 12 columns.

So a temporary fix that i found for this was to not include sidebar.php in the index.php and include it in all the 3 files which needed it and then making the jQuery script change "#main-content" which contained the whole structure of the webpage except for header and footer.

The reason that made me ask this question is because the time is up for the temporary fix as i've started to face many problems due to that like extra bytes of data being loaded every time leading to slow load up times, part of jquery (which interacted with a button on the sidebar) works only once, and many more.

For the simplicity, i've removed all the text from the code but i'm leaving the comments there as they might help.

My index file is:

```
<?php require 'includes/header.php'; ?>

<?php require 'about.php'; ?>

<?php require 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

The markup in the header and footer files is completely correct that's why i've left it out.

My about.php and other files (file2.php and file3.php) with the sidebar have the following markup but with different text.

```
<!-- Main Content -->
<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 ">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-11 col-lg-11 panel pad1">    
                    <!-- Page Content -->
                    <div id="page-content">
                    </div><!-- Page Content -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div>
        <?php require 'includes/sidebar.php'; ?>
    </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- main-content -->
```

My other two files (say without_sidebar1.php and without_sidebar2.php) have the following markup:

```
<!-- Main Content -->
<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
            <div class="row panel pad1 ">
                <!-- Page Content -->
                <div id="page-content">
                    text
                </div><!-- Page Content -->
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- main-content -->
```

The markup of the sidebar.php

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 sidebar">
    <div class="row">
        some text
    </div><!-- row -->
</div>
```

and now finally my jQuery

```
var main = function () {
    var current_page = $(".nav li.active-page"); 
    var previous_page_content = $("#page-content").html();
    var previous_main_content = $("#main-content").html();

    $(".nav li").hover(function(){
        current_page.removeClass("active-page");
        $(this).addClass("active-page");
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active-page");
        current_page.addClass("active-page");
    });

    $(".nav li").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        current_page = $(this);
        current_page.addClass("active-page");

        var goToUrl = $('.nav .active-page a').attr('href');
        var pageLoaded = false;

        var changing_div = $("#main-content");

        NProgress.configure({ parent: '#page-content'});
        NProgress.start();

        if (pageLoaded === false) {
            $.ajax({
                url: goToUrl,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) { 
                    changing_div.html(data);
                    NProgress.done();
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    changing_div.load('404.html');
                    NProgress.done();
                }
            });
        }

    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

The script is the one i'm using currently as a temporary fix. How should i edit my script and files to achieve the desired results. 
(Desired results are: sidebar should be included in index.php after adding the appropriate markup before and after it)

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 ">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-11 col-lg-11 panel pad1">    
                    <!-- Page Content -->
                    <div id="page-content">
                    </div><!-- Page Content -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div>
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 sidebar">
            <div class="row">
        </div>          
    </div><!-- container -->
</div>
```

Currently getting:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 ">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-11 col-lg-11 panel pad1">    
                        <!-- Page Content -->
                        <div id="page-content" class=" ">
                            some text here
                        </div><!-- Page Content -->
                    </div>
                </div><!-- row -->
            </div>
                            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 sidebar">
                <div class="row">
                    some text here
                </div><!-- row -->
            </div>          
        </div><!-- container -->
    </div><!-- main-content -->
</div>
```

Yes two #main-content(s). Idk why.

I've used stackoverflow from last 2 years but this is the first question i'm asking.

I've asked this question after working 15 hours straight which is the main reason for the bad framed language of this question, apologies for that. Tiniest of help for any part that you think i'm doing wrong and obviously for the main issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"The loading of other pages happened without any issues till they were html files, but as soon as i changed them over to php files (because i needed to add more functionality), the website started to break."

There is your problem. PHP is server side, you cannot just add php code into a web page that is already rendered to the client (browser) and expect it to run. You have to set up your AJAX so that it runs the php on the server side and returns HTML result.

Comment: "You have to set up your AJAX so that it runs the php on the server side and returns HTML result."

i could be wrong but i believe that's what i'm doing there in the jquery script, my ajax requests to the php file and the php returns html content. 

what am i not getting? :\

Comment: Possibly. It is very hard for me to follow what you are dong because you are going about it in a very different way than how I would do it. Not saying your way is not better, just different and hard for me to follow. The only advice I have is to use simple test pages for your main content. One just `<p>Test</p>` and the other `<?php echo('<p>Test</p>'); ?>`. That way you will know if php is what is messing you up. If it is not then start adding your actual content one small thing at a time until you get to the one that produces the undesirable result.

Comment: Lemme try those test cases and i'll get back to you with the results. And if you don't mind me telling, what's the approach that you use?

Comment: I don't know the exact constraints that you are working with but I would probably use php to deliver each page instead of trying to alter the page client-side with AJAX. It is so easy to `include` .php pages within each other that you may be making your life harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Well that is certainly there but as i understand php pretty well and i am comfortable with it, i wanted to try my hand at ajax loading, which is something i wasn't that comfortable with, and i find that better than reloading pages, just my opinion. This project is my own pet project so i was just on a learning trip for this. And as now i've accomplished my goals for the current version, i'll try that approach you specified above in the comments.